# Paris, the catacombs, anti-gravity skate punks

Tags: story-identification, cyberpunk, artificial-gravity

There was a book I read in the 90's, I guess. Set in Paris, it followed a bunch of punks who spent their time having firework fights in the catacombs under Paris, skating the streets on their anti-gravity skates, dressed in leathers, high, listening to soundscapes mapped to the geography of the streets.

The hero meets a crazy uptown heiress and after having an affair that ends badly, she tries to kill him, so he gathers his friends and invades her family's flying pyramid home.

God, I loved this book and I can't believe it isn't a famous classic. I suspect I read it when I was like 14 and in fact it was rubbish. ...but I don't really believe that, the ideas in it were so good.

Oh, and there was a bad guy called Two Tone, because his hair was dyed two colours, only then he dyed it all one so they called him... *shit, I can't believe how bizarrely memory works.*

Please god someone tell me the title because it's killing me.

Answer (score 6):

The book is "[Bad Voltage](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Bad-Voltage-Jonathon-Littell/dp/0747405840)" by Jonathon Littell

> "In the Paris of the future, a group of punk outlaws run riot. One of
>   the gang rebels against the punks' newest fetish of cannibalism and
>   becomes involved in an adventure with a computer network situated
>   inside a stolen necklace."

[image: Bad Voltage Cover]

Littell himself described the book as "**[a very bad science-fiction novel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jonathan_Littell)**". It's also notable that his next book won the Literary Review's annual "[Bad sex in Fiction](http://www.literaryreview.co.uk/badsex.html)" award.

Comment: Dear Richard, thank you, I don't remember the canabalism but I do remember that cover, with those terrible haircuts, even that tagline. I'm looking forward to rereading it, good or bad.

Comment: When even the author slates it, you know it's gonna be bad. I expect you to report back afterwards...

Comment: [The Kindly Ones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Kindly_Ones_(Littell_novel)) (which won the Bad Sex in Fiction award) is a controversial, incredibly well-researched, interesting, and very successful book that really disgusted me on multiple levels. Just saying this to point out it's a lot more than the (kitschy and repetitive) porn in it. Littell is a very talented, if really weird, writer.

Comment: So his professed disgust at his own writing may be less about self-knowledge and more about self-publicity.

Comment: @gervase - Just a quick reminder that you've not yet pressed the "accepted" button to mark my answer as correct.